# Trying to debug my bot but nothing shows up

Tags: discord.js

Hi this is my code for my discord bot, I try to run it and it comes up without an error, even the "im alive" log comes up in console, but nothing else, thought it was my token but the bot logs in,
the only thing I can think of is the `client.on` but even in doc's I cant see the diffrence.
Im new to js so anybody's help is appreciated

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client({intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS]});

const prefix = '!';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log("I'm alive!");
});

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log('asd');
    if(message.content = '${prefix}hi'){
        console.log('command detected');
        message.channel.send('Hi ${message.author}');
    }
});

client.login('my-token');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the message data, you need to enable the `GUILD_MESSAGES` intent in your client as well as you need to go to your [Discord Developer](https://discord.com/developers/applications) page and then in your application, go to the Bot option and the check the Message Content Intent

Comment: Thanks m8 its working now, but instead of messaging back with my name it prints "Hi ${message.author}"

Comment: First of all `message.author` gives you an object which `discord.js` won't be able to send so you will have to use `message.author.tag` if you want the discriminator and `message.author.username` if you just want the username. Second of all, instead of doing 'Hi ${message.author}', use backticks or the tilde instead of the single quotes